# Zeroes of Mellin transform

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, integral-transforms

There exist a "standard" or canonical way to construct a real valued function whose Mellin transform has a prescribed set of zeroes? Clearly for some set of zeroes this could be impossible but for the "admissible ones"?

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Presumably the basic approach would be to construct a function with a certain set of zeroes, and then take an inverse Mellin transform. To make the inverse transform real-valued, the original function should have some other conjugate-symmetry property, but this seems possible to check for functions constructed via Weierstrass factorization.

Comment: The problem with this approach for me is that I can't guarantee that the function will be integrable along vertical lines in the complex plane.